# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyCoordinator menuTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, delegates

I was facing crash randomly, I've a bar button upon tapping on it i will call a method inside it executes delegate method, I didn't get exact solution for this it shows crash at the delegate method.

[image]

**> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyCoordinator menuTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000113d60a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20421af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204306f7 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20425dc0 ***forwarding*** + 859
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20428068 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   ServiceExpress                      0x000000010adfec84 -[MyCoordinator menuTapped] + 68
6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2469d19e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23bc95bd -[UIBarButtonItem _triggerActionForEvent:] + 158
8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23ba0e1b __45-[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:]_block_invoke + 39
9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23ba0ccc -[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:] + 152
10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2469d19e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23fc6684 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223
12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23fc69a7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 332
13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23fc5290 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 500
14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246d984e -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1287
15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246db6c7 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4774
16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246b5466 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 633
17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24745f04 __processEventQueue + 13895
18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2473c877 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 104
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2039038a **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20390282 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 180
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038f764 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 248
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20389f2f __CFRunLoopRun + 878
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203896d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
24  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2c257db3 GSEventRunModal + 139
25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24696cf7 -[UIApplication _run] + 912
26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2469bba8 UIApplicationMain + 101
27  ServiceExpress                      0x000000010adf57d1 main + 97
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff2025a3e9 start + 1
29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyCoordinator menuTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000113d60a0'**

```
UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImageName"]
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:@selector(menuTapped)];
menuButton.tintColor = accentContrastcolor;
contentViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[menuButton];
```

Here i'm calling the selector method in MyCoordinator.

```
- (void)menuTapped
{
    [self.delegate menuButtonTapped:self]; //Crash happend here
}
```

in MyCoordinator @interface

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyCoordinatorDelegate> delegate;
```

Protocol methods

```
 @protocol MyCoordinatorDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)menuButtonTapped:(MyTreeCoordinator *)myCoordinator;

@end
```

Implementaion is done in another VC

```
extension MyVC: MyCoordinatorDelegate {
    func menuButtonTapped(_ myCoordinator: MyTreeCoordinator) {
        /// statements
    }
}
```

IN MyVC  confirmed that protocol.

```
myCoordinator!.delegate = self
```

Comment: `self.delegate` is a `MyCoordinator` instance. Does it have a method `-(void)menuButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;`?

Comment: Yes it's a delegate method inside protocol it is added like this - (void)menuButtonTapped:(MyCoordinator *)myCoordinator;

Comment: But does `MyCoordinator` implements it? It's unclear, it seems that the `delegate` is itself? Could you add the declaration of the protocol, implementation in which class also that implements its, where is the delegate, in the question not in comment

Comment: According to the error: `self.delegate` is a `MyCoordinator` not a `MyVC`. So where did you do `self.delegate = ...` or `[self setDelegate:..]`

Comment: yes in MyCoordinator .m class implemented this, I've added in  question can you check that - (void)menuTapped
{
    [self.delegate menuButtonTapped:self]; //Crash happend here
}

Comment: It's saying at runtime self in the definition of your menuButton has no selector called menuTapped. What is self in that context? I'm assuming that's where - (void)menuTapped is declared.

Comment: Did you try to add parameter to menuTapped like :(UIBarButyonItem *)sender

Comment: @PtitXav When I add parameter at the end it always crashing. Without this it crashed very randomly.

Comment: Did you try to add menuTapped in MyCoordinator interface ? Or declare it as an @IBAction ?

Comment: No Created barbutton as programmatically and added as NavigationItem rightBarButtonItems.

Comment: Any idea? to fix this isse.